# iOS 9 new back button animation

Tags: ios, button, ios9

So apple brought some new functions with iOS9.. One of these is the tiny black back-button, which appears when I open an app over a popup or something like that.

In my app the user can press a button to enter the settings. Then this new button appears. I was able to register, when this button was pressed, but as soon as the animation appears, there is such a black background. Is there a possibility to change the color of this animation-background?

As you can see, I mean this button:

[image]

This black background:

[image]